# ECG plotting in IOS using Core Plot library.

Tags: ios, xcode, core-plot

I'm trying to plot a **ECG** on an **IOS** application using **Core Plot** library like [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9ZTfR4AHq-c) .I have tried to plot ECG like in the video in my IOS APP.I got the following result.

[image]

In general *ECG* graph should be plotted from the left end of the graph(***Lead 1 in Screen shot***) after a specific time interval.When i'm plotting *ECG* in my APP after the specified time interval,*Each graph gets plotted on top of the previous graph*.
**How can we solve this**?

Comment: Is each group of data points plotted on a separate plot, or are you adding points to a single plot? What do you want to happen? Should the time-series continue to the right, replace the old plot data with new data, or something else?

Comment: I want to replace the old plot data with new data...and maintain a void gap between old and new plot like the video mentioned above.

Comment: UPDATE:
When I used 
`[thePlot reloadDataInIndexRange:NSMakeRange(arrayIndex, arrayIndex+100)];`
There is a line is connecting between old graph and new graph.How can i avoid this?

Comment: CPU usage also high when i'm using `reloadDataInIndexRange`.

Comment: Hi @AjithJohn. I am trying to plot ECG as well. My X axis is date and y axis is point, for eg X = 24/04/2018 and Y = 48. I tried but got points connected to each other instead. Can you please post your code also.? I would be of great help. Please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement this similar to the "Real Time Plot" demo in the *Plot Gallery* example app, although your application is a little simpler since you don't need to update the plot space after each frame of new data. You can leave a gap in the plot line by inserting a data point with a `NSNull` or `NAN` value between the points on either side of the break.

The plot must redraw after every change to the plot data, so you need to balance the size (pixel dimensions) of the plot and the number of data points with the desired update rate. Note that ranges are specified with a start location and the length of the range. To add a new data point and move the blank space over one spot, reload a range starting at the `arrayIndex` and length of two (2). Increment the `arrayIndex` for each new point and wrap around to index zero (0) when you get to the end.